# Azure runbook rename SQL database

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

In Azure, I want to rename a SQL database with a PowerShell automation runbook with the command:

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> 
   -ServerName <ServerName> -DatabaseName <DatabaseName> -NewName <NewName>
```

according to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/set-azurermsqldatabase?view=azurermps-6.13.0

This command works fine in the Launch Cloud Shell from the top navigation of the Azure portal.

But in a runbook, it does not work with this error:

> Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'NewName'.

It seems that `-NewName` is missing in a runbook

```
   Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase `
        -DatabaseName <System.String> `
        -ResourceGroupName <System.String> `
        [-ElasticPoolName <System.String>] `
        [-Tags <System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]>] `
        [-RequestedServiceObjectiveName <System.String>] `
        -ServerName <System.String> `
        [-Edition <Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Database.Model.DatabaseEdition>] `
        [-MaxSizeBytes <System.Int64>]
```

Comment: are you piping the parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm expecting that you are running the runbook from an Azure Automation Account.

Depending on when you created the Azure Automation Account, your accounts modules might be outdated.

A simple way to prove this is to create a new runbook and put this into it:

```
Get-Command Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase
```

Execute the runbook from the portal and view the output. You will be surprised to see what module version it will report back to you.

Luckily I had an very old Automation Account laying around to prove it for you:

[image]

Results:
[image]

After the update

[image]

The results are:

[image]

Comment: You could also do a `Get-Help Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -Full` from the runbook and see the parameters available

Comment: I take it that I was spot on with the issue :)